# System Device Location not working

Tags: c#, windows, geolocation

I have code for using the system.device.location api found in windows computers. This should be fairly straightfoward code

```
var watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();
        watcher.PositionChanged +=
new EventHandler<GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<
    GeoCoordinate>>(GeoPositionChanged);
        watcher.Start();
        var coord = watcher.Position.Location;
```

I mean all I need to do is start a geo watcher and then read the location. But it only ever returns "Location Unknown" and I am wondering if there is an issue with the code, or if something needs to be installed on the computer, or what. I have tried this with a few windows 7 pcs and 1 windows 10 pc and all of them have the share location turned on in the settings. So what is wrong with this code? Also this is the code for the geopositionchanged if that makes any difference.

```
    private static void GeoPositionChanged(object sender,
GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The current location is: " +
            e.Position.Location.Latitude + "/" +
            e.Position.Location.Longitude + ".");
    }
```

Comment: Wait for location services to be ready. Your GeoCoordinateWatcher has an event for status change and another one for position change.

Comment: I encountered an issue in asp.net mvc that geo location is not working if your site is not SSL enabled

Answer (score 2):

Wait for location services to be ready. Your GeoCoordinateWatcher has an event for status change and another one for position change.

```
    GeoCoordinateWatcher _watcher;
    public Class1()
    {
        _watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();
        _watcher.StatusChanged += Watcher_StatusChanged;
        _watcher.PositionChanged += GeoPositionChanged;

        _watcher.Start();
        var coord = _watcher.Position.Location;
    }

    private void Watcher_StatusChanged(object sender, GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Status == GeoPositionStatus.Ready)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Watcher is ready. First location: The current location is: " +
          _watcher.Position.Location.Latitude + "/" +
          _watcher.Position.Location.Longitude + ".");
        }
    }

    private static void GeoPositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The current location is: " +
            e.Position.Location.Latitude + "/" +
            e.Position.Location.Longitude + ".");
    }
```

Comment: No dice, still returns unknown

Comment: Which version of Windows are you using? What is the value of 'e.Status'? Please use a breakpoint to view the value.

Comment: It says initializing

Comment: IT doesn't hit a second time.It says initialize when it starts and then it trys to get position.location and that's it.

Comment: Ok, normally the status is NoData (e.g. no permission to retrieve the data) or Ready. Which version of Windows are you using?

Comment: Windows 10 I added a for loop that slept if the status wasn't ready. It works now.... Although I am not convinced this is the best way to do this.

Comment: A for-loop is not the right way to solve this issue. Maybe you can turn the location setting off and on again? Your Windows 10 settings screen should look like [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/ximg_559ac0bf02870.png.pagespeed.gp+jp+jw+pj+js+rj+rp+rw+ri+cp+md.ic.dFvXhAQ9Ua.png)

Comment: I changed the for loop to a single sleep and it works now. Not really sure why. But it works.